# Time type column field data update in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a time type column in database and i want to update current stored value.
I wrote this query but data is not changed.

UPDATE testing SET timevall = timevall + "06:00:00" WHERE timevall > "00:00:00"

Kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: what is stored in timevall? another thing, in PHP `+ ` with string does not make any sense, if you want to concatenate, you should use `dot (.)`

Comment: i have stored time in timevall column

Comment: Con you create a example in [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? This helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query its work fine for you..

```
update testing set timevall=now() WHERE timevall > "00:00:00";
```

its store current time in timevall..

try this its works and gives output which youwant

```
UPDATE testing SET timevall = ADDTIME(timevall, '12:00:00') WHERE timevall > '00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks it really worked but i want to add 12 hours to current stored value.can you please guide me?

Comment: hi...Qazi just copi my answer bro...you should correct my answer not his...anyway thanks....remember next time ...

Comment: sorry i just saw both so i marked one.dot worry i mark that too i don't what that means but i do it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE testing SET timevall = ADDTIME(timevall, '12:00:00') WHERE timevall > '00:00:00';
```